# GWT - sending data from GWT Client to non-Java Server

Tags: sql-server, json, gwt, iis

We have a GWT Application that displays editable rows of data that are populated on the client using JsonpRequestBuilder via a C# Handler that produces JSONP to feed the client.  Our Web server is IIS (no Java access unfortunately) and our Database is SQL Server.

The issue we are facing is **how do we best communicate the changes made on the client back to the server so that we can update/delete/add rows to our SQL Server Database**?

Our ideal solution would be for the user to make their changes to the displayed rows, then press a Save button that will send all of the data needed to perform the CRUD on the SQL Server.  Since we can't send this data as Java Objects, should we consider sending them to the server as JSON?  If so, what GWT method can be used to do this?

It seems that most of the documentation/samples/tutorials focus on sending information from the Server to the Client...any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First idea I have is to create a WCF REST service that stores data in SQL Server and invoke it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Since GWT RPC mechanism requires Java you could turn to [RequestBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) which could send and fetch JSON from the server. There is an article about your issue in [the official documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of server communications.

- RPC
- Request Builder

### RPC:

Collect the data from the client (UI layer) and send the data to your service layer through RPC mechanism and update your object from the service layer. Communicating the web service and update the db is also possible through RPC service

### Request Builder:

If the data base update part is available as a web service, then submit your data through request builder and do the update operation.

Comment: Are you saying you can use RPC with a C# Handler instead of a Java servlet (as the author of the question requires) ? I doubt that, but if you have some resources about that topic would you care to share them with me ?

Comment: My point here is, from the RPC service you can call any web service and get the data. But our RPC service should be in java. Because it has to be registered in our web context. I hope this will clear your doubt

Comment: I think it's best to stick to the question. Check point 3 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer